# Python get all the contents from a website to html file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

someone please help, i want to transfer all to contents from url to a html file can someone help me please? I have to use user-agent too!

Comment: Can you share URL, expected output, what code you've done so far?

Comment: have you tried a tutorial? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/beautiful_soup/index.htm

Comment: Down vote because you didn't post any code, or even really give a description of the problem other than "i need help"

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO, when you ask a question you need to submit the code that you have tried, [here's where you can learn to ask a question properly.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Regarding your question, when you say "I want to transfer all to contents from url to a html file" I am assuming you just want to read the page source and save it in a file.

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = r.get("http://example.com", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)

file = open('myfile.html', 'w')
file.writelines(soup)
file.close()
```

if you get an error called TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Tag, just typecast soup to string.

```
file.writelines(str(soup))
```

Answer (score 0):

because I don't know what site you need scrape so I say a few wasy

if site contains JS frontend and for laoding needed waiting then I recommend you use `requests_html` module which has method for rendering content

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "https://some-url.org"

with HTMLSession() as session:
    response = session.get(url)
    response.html.render() #  rendering JS code
    content = response.html.html #  full content
```

if site doesn't use JS for frontent then `requests` module is really good choice for you

```
import requests

url = "https://some-url.org"

response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content #  html content in bytes()
```

else you can use `selenium` webdriver but it works few slowly for python