# How to request specific HTML divisions?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I want to read-in the financial statements from this website:
https://investors.sgx.com/_security-types/stocks/502

My current code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url='https://investors.sgx.com/_security-types/stocks/502')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

However, the output is incomplete and very brief as it does not show the specific data i want

I believe the details I want are under `'div class="website-main-content"'`, but they are not shown.

How do I access the specific division straight away when making a html request?

Comment: data u want are from requests made by javascript (to a soap server, which means u send XML data with your request and it returns again some XML). Getting those data could be tricky, I cant tell you how exactly you can do it, cause those datas are result of chain of requests. 

Good way to observe what is going on is to use chrome dev tools, look to the network tab whats being send, XHR type requests are those from JS, which eventualy returns your data.

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394852/python-get-all-the-contents-from-a-website-to-html-file/62395458#62395458 I answered your question

Comment: Thank you. And i tried 

url = 'https://investors.sgx.com/_security-types/stocks/502'

with HTMLSession() as session:
    response = session.get(url)
    response.html.render() #  rendering JS code
    content = response.html.html #  full content                                                                 but it gives the error RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.